# Retaining AJAX generated content when using history.back

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where an AJAX call is made and when it is completed, an image link as well as other data is returned. The data is populated into input fields and a new `<img>` tag is generated for the image link.

However, if I leave the page and call `history.back(1)`, the input data persists but the image does not. Is there any way to keep generated tags when calling `history.back(1)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage` to store the data through the session history of the page.

When AJAX finishes successfully, image data can be stored in the local storage. For example, if you are going to store this data in a variable `imageData`, saving it in a key called `image`:

```js
// successful AJAX
localStorage.setItem('image', imageData);
```

Then, use a listener (`.onpopstate`) to check whenever the session history changed.
Like this, you can regenerate the tags again.

```
window.onpopstate = function() {

  let imageStorage = localStorage.getItem('image');

  if (imageStorage != null) {
    // regenerate tags
  }
}
```